# Getting iDevices iOS version over C

Tags: ios, c

I've been getting into iOS development recently, but I can't figure out how to get the iOS version over USB in a C program.

I've tried reverse-engineering the `ideviceinfo` source on GitHub, but I still cant work it out.

My questions are:

- What headers do I need
- How do I get the iOS version

**NOTE:**

I do not want to use external applications and scripts like `iDeviceInfo`.

I would be happy with links to documentation, tutorials, raw code etc

Comment: What do you mean by "over USB"? Where is your program running?

Comment: So, lets say I connect my USB, type `./GetiOSVersion`, then it prints `iOS Version: 7.1.2`. So I'm running Linux.